# How to map master page to the application page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, master-page, application-pages

Hello I created a application page in visual studio 2010. Now i want to mapp this to our master page. the default master page is, applicationv4.master. Now to map this to our application page?
I changed in the application page for the `dynamicmasterpagefile` attribute in the Page directive as `DynamicMasterPageFile = "~/_layouts/application.master"` .
After deploying the solution i am getting following error.
[image]

How to avoid this. I searched a lot, but didn't find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the soulution for my problem. Following is the final markup.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="AppPages.Layouts.AppPages.ApplicationPage1"   EnableViewState="false" EnableViewStateMac="false"    %>
```

Removed codebehind file, and added `enableviewstate` and `enableviewstatemac` attributes. 
Just copied from the `viewlists.aspx` page  **page directive**

Comment: If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to update MasterPageFile property to new masterpage. This works perfectly fine in one of my application pages.`<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/MCPT/Collaboration.Master" Inherits="Collaboration.Tool.ApplicationPages.ChangePassword" EnableViewState="true" EnableViewStateMac="true"%>`

Comment: @Nadeem.. need to change any thing in the tag provided by you? When I copy paste the same thing the error is still showing.

Comment: @Mihir, you need to specify MasterPageFile attribute instead of  DynamicMasterPageFile atrribute. Also, make sure you are specifying the proper path.

Answer (score 0):

Late Answer....What worked for me is this

Just replace  `DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"` with `MasterPageFile="../ttl.master"`

Where ttl.master is the master page you want to use

See Below

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="xxxxx.aspx.cs" Inherits="TSharePointProject.Layouts.TSharePointProject.xxxxx" MasterPageFile="../ttl.master" %>
```